# How to change only the selected setence of a file which is open with jfilechooser without changing the original file?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I am creating a translator which opens a file with jFileChooser and what I am trying to do is to **change a sentence that I have selected with a bottom.**

For instance, imagine I have a file that contains *Hello my name is Pablo and I love coding.*

When I open it with jFileChooser I want to select, for instance, "love coding" and press a button in order to change what appears on the screen for another word (e.g. "dog").

I know you can change what appears in the box with `box.append("dog")` and you can get the sentence you have just selected with `box.getSelectedText()`.

Can you please help me to change the contents of the box, but only the selected sentence?

Here you have an image, you can think I want to change the box content by adding "dog" instead of what is selected.

[image]

Comment: Have you visited this Web page? [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Comment: The API is your friend. Method [`replaceSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#replaceSelection-java.lang.String-) in class `JTextComponent`.

Answer (score -1):

One way as follows:

```
String orgBoxContent = box.getText();
String selectedText = box.getSelectedText();

orgBoxContent = orgBoxContent.replaceFirst(selectedText,"dog");
box = new JTextArea(orgBoxContent);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do: `box.setText(orgBoxContent)` ? (Rather than create a new `JTextArea` which you would need to add to some parent container, anyway, right?)

Comment: Of course, I did not know exactly what method is right. The tutorials from Oracle spoke  from `new JTextArea()`.

Comment: (1-) This is not how to change data in a text component. The text is stored in a `Document`. Changes should be made to the `Document` (as suggested by Abra in the comments above). This solution is very inefficient. The getText() method needs to get the data from the Document build a text String. Then you use a regex to parse the text String and replace the data. Finally the setText() method needs to parse the text string for newline characters and rebuild the Document.

Comment: @camickr The topic is for me clear. No changes in open file (document?)

Comment: The file has nothing to do with this. Al Swing text components store the data in a Document. The text component doesn't know or care where the data comes from.

Comment: Thank you all! I get it. To answer you, I did not want to change the document, but the content of the jTextArea.